# php code not working in phped

Tags: php, phped

I am setting up my php project on phped, but it will be running html file but cannot ruining php function and other ajax or java script file copy that code will be ruining on the other server in phped same visions fine but in my new server its show that error kindly help me to fixed that problem.html and some of the code is ruining fine but a lot of but function code is show error.

you can see the error in that link :

http://screencast.com/t/gP0I39tJXt

http://screencast.com/t/pPjl9gOj

Answer (score 0):

Php editors don't evaluate PHP code like HTML, those only allow to edit code with cute formatting and useful features.
For running PHP code, you need web server like apache or nginx.